# passing stdin to a command called in a function

Tags: powershell

I have a python script that I wrapped in a function call. The script is `scr` and the function is `function scr {python (Join-Path $ENV:HOME "bin\scr") $args}`. When I call python directly, it accepts stdin fine. So `echo hello | python bin\scr` works. But when I call the function (`echo hello | scr`), then stdin is not passed from the pipe to the python script but seems to still come from the terminal. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can extend your function with the `[CmdletBinding]` attribute. This will allow you to pipe to it. [See here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847872.aspx) for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$input` automatic variable, which represent pipeline input to your function. Also you can use `$MyInvocation.ExpectingInput` to find out did your function expect any pipeline input or not.

```
function scr {
    $MyArgs=(Join-Path $ENV:HOME "bin\scr"),$args
    if($MyInvocation.ExpectingInput){
        $input | python @MyArgs
    }else{
        python @MyArgs
    }
}
```