# Using CmdletBinding without formal parameters

Tags: powershell

Following a comment to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456123/passing-stdin-to-a-command-called-in-a-function), I tried adding CmdletBinding to a function. Here is a toy example

```
function example {
  [CmdletBinding()]Param()
  $args
}
```

But trying to use it I get:

```
> example foo
example : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'foo'.
At line:1 char:1
+ example foo
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [example], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,example
```

What should I fix so that the function will work with any argument(s) passed to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare a parameter to accept that `"foo"` within the `Param()` block. [Here's the manual on advanced parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx). In your case, you want the parameter to accept any value that's not matched to any other parameters (none), so you declare it using `ValueFromRemainingArguments` argument set to true.

```
function example {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)][String[]] $args
    )
    $args
}
```

An example on how to use:

```
PS K:\> example foo bar hum
foo
bar
hum
```

Comment: This doesn't work with `example -v` or `example -args -v`

Comment: `-v` is verbose flag, it is matched by `[cmdletbinding()]` and sets local `$verbosepreference` variable to true, or if written `-v:$false`, to false. You can make it display by quoting, `example "-v"`.

Comment: Just tried `example -vvv` and got the `-vvv` in result. Anyway, what do you actually want?